# How to solve it? Mp4 video progress bar (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to read mp4 files with PHP, my initial code was

```
$file = 'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4';

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
readfile($file);
```

But that way I couldn't use the length bar of the video, skip or even go back, until the video is 100% loaded.
Of course when I read the file directly (video.mp4) everything is fine.

Comment: Why not read the file directly instead? Any specific reason why you're using PHP as a proxy? If a user has a fast connection, it will never be faster than your server + if multiple people are looking at video at the same time, it could become pretty slow pretty quick.

Comment: I could open it directly with amazon, I might have to do a fopen, and this will make playback very slow, I've already tested it.

Comment: I mean in your front-end, why not link directly to the video file on Amazon instead of piping it through your PHP-file?

Comment: Because I do not want to leave the link exposed, so I'm hiding in php, but I'm having this problem when reading mp4, sorry for my bad english

Comment: do you have a solution to not leave the link exposed?

Comment: I just don't understand why it matters, since anyone can download the file either way. You're actually not gaining anything. Seems like a high cost on your web server (in form of higher network traffic) for very little gain.

Comment: There is a difference between the people of TI download and everyone download, this would cost me dearly, not counting the possibility of complaints, etc. If it were irrelevant, Netflix, youtube, and porn sites, would not dedicate themselves to making download difficult .

Comment: If you have the amazon link in your front end, people can access it directly. If you have a link to your php-file instead, people just need to go to that link directly and download the file. If someone wants to download the file, they just check the URL in the front end and they can access it regardless. It will be exactly the same for the users, unless you have some more code in the file, like CSRF or authentication before.

Comment: Big companies, like you mention, are usually having other measures to protect their files from direct downloads plus that they are usually using CDN's with their own domains.

Comment: I sure will have other security measures in the code to prevent the download, but the question is not this, the issue the reproduction of video / mp4 in PHP

Answer (score -1):

Get the header of the Amazon request (curl) and forward it. Scrubbing will never work though.

UPDATE:

```
curl -I https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4
>>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: Ykt6rmYagUDTbKW+v2DR63Zb4ZmUJCM8ty7hO+Z/BU9DV5w1PTVEk+khHgMp+eoR7ExxzKy1Ius=
x-amz-request-id: 8F7A552FAB8D8B08
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 08:12:26 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 09:46:10 GMT
ETag: "adcafc77564f72b5e21574f4bfc4e927"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: **1386059** < to forward.
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: and how do you suggest?

Comment: See above. Might help regarding instant playback.